# How to replace value in col 4 with X if col 1 is the same as col 3, else replace each entry in col 4 with col 2 using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
A01 106403746   A01 0
A01 106720129   A01 690201.72
A01 106420797   A01 1345008.48
A01 106021633   A01 1345008.48
A01 106021630   A01 1345008.48
A01 106369397   A01 1345008.48
A01 77894226    A01 3291731.28
A01 106625479   A01 3291731.28
B01 112178282   A01 3291731.28
A01 77599901    A01 3291731.28
A01 106805991   A01 3291731.28
A01 106885583   A01 3291731.28
A01 106642966   A01 3291731.28
A01 106545175   A01 3291731.28
A05 44887670    A01 3291731.28
```

Tried:

```
awk '{if ($1 == $3) print $1"\t"$2"\t"$3"\t"$4==x}' input_file|less -S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite basic:

```
awk '$1==$3{$4="X";print;next}{$4=$2}1' file
```

You don't need `if` formula, just put the condition in front of braces.

Comment: Maybe: `awk '{$4=($1==$3)?"X":$2}1' file`