# Match the numeric values of alphanumeric string using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file looks like below as a sample:

```
B01 112178282 A01 112178282
A05 44887670 A01 44887670
B01 114451441 A01 114451441
B10 8364597 A01 8364597
B01 123453906 A01 123453906
A05 9155966 A01 9155966
A05 86420950 A01 86420950
A10 75684694 A01 75684694
A04 71261964 A01 71261964
B01 1262441 A01 1262441
B01 471272 A01 471272
B01 17007 A01 17007
A04 115637044 A01 115637044
A07 9376758 A01 9376758
```

I want to have two separate output files

1. When `num val in col1 == num val in col3`
2. second output file When `num val in col 1 != num val in col 3`

For an example, col1 is B01 and col3 A01, here in both columns the numeric part is same `01`. Now, all such conditions should be listed in file1.

If col1 is A05 and col3 is A01, here in both columns the numeric part is different `07 != 01`, then these should be listed in another file2

Comment: A follow up to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/382491/203203? Or is it an assignment? What did you try?

Comment: The only new requirement is to write the result to **two files**.  Is that all ?. Then: What have you tried? What is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'substr($1,2)==substr($3,2) { print $0 > "file1" } substr($1,2) != substr($3,2) { print $0 > "file2" }' masterfile
```

With masterfile containing the original data and using the substr function of awk, we ignore the first letter of the first and third space delimited fields leaving us with the numbers to compare. We then perform conditional checks on these numbers placing them in specific files (file1 and file2) accordingly.

Comment: good point to using `substr`, also you could use `if/else` to avoid adding another condition `substr($1,2) != substr($3,2)` or using "Ternary operator" as in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/382520/72456) , + by default awk prints whole line no need to have `$0` with print

Comment: Good points but not very understandable for novices. It's good to give the poster a variety of solution strategies though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` will produce two files; Those lines which 1<sup>st</sup>&3<sup>rd</sup> columns' numeric parts were same will goes in a separate file and those lines where these columns were different into the another file.

```
awk -F"[A B]" '{
    print >(($2==$5)?"matches.txt":"non_matches.txt")
}' infile.txt
```

This will set awk's field separator to sets of `A`, `B` or Space characters, then do compare, if numeric parts were same then current line will write to "matches.txt" file, else it will write to "non_matches.txt" file.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -alMFatal=open -pe '
   BEGIN{ unlink, open *{+uc}, ">>$_" for qw/file1.log file2.log/; }
   select $F[0] =~ s/^\D*//r eq $F[2] =~ s/^\D*//r ? *{"FILE1.LOG"} : *{"FILE2.LOG"};
' sample.txt
```

---

## Explanation

- `Perl` options:

  - `-a` will split the line into fields based on whitespace and those fields are available via `$F[0] $F[1] ...`
  - `-l` will set the `RS` to newline and `ORS` to newline.
  - `-M` will load the module `Fatal.pm` and include a function `open` from it's namespace. This means that any errors in opening a file in the main code shall die.
  - `-p` will read the sample.txt file line-by-line and auto-printing of lines is enabled after all transformations have been applied to it.
- The `BEGIN` block shall remove any existing file1.log and file2.log and open filehandles in an `append` mode to files.
- `select` command chooses the filehandle on which to print the current line.

  - `$F[0] =~ s/^\D*//r` shall strip any leading nondigits in the first field (this assumes all digits are placed at the end of the field).
  - We perform a similar operation on the 3rd field ($F[2]) and then compare these results in a string format (and NOT in numeric, since 001 = 1 in numeric). When the strings match we select the filehandle *FILE1.LOG which means the current line is printed here, due to the `-p` option. OTW, the filehandle *FILE2.LOG is made the default handle and the `-p` option makes `Perl` prints the current line here.

---

We can do the same using `sed` tool as well as shown: (Assuming GNU sed)

```
sed -Ee '
   h;s/\S+/\n&\n/3
   /^[^0-9[:blank:]]*([0-9]+).*\n(.*[^0-9])?\1\n/{
      g
      s/^//w file1.log
      d
   }
   g
' < sample.txt > file2.log
```

---

- In the first step we enclose the third field via markers.
- Then we perform the comparison of the digits in the trailing portion of the first field to match with the digits in the trailing portion of the third field.
- On match, we recall the hold space where we had stored the current line sans the markers and append it in file1.log file.
- On no match, we recall the hold space and let it go to stdout where it is stored in the file2.log file by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed` with an editing script (adjust the path and name of GNU `sed` on the first line to match your system):

```
#!/usr/bin/sed -nrf

/^[A-Z]([0-9]+) [0-9]+ [A-Z]\1 [0-9]+$/{
    w match.txt
    b
}
w nonmatch.txt
```

Running this on the example file will produce the two result files `match.txt` and `nonmatch.txt`:

```
$ chmod +x script.sed

$ ./script.sed file.in

$ cat match.txt
B01 112178282 A01 112178282
B01 114451441 A01 114451441
B01 123453906 A01 123453906
B01 1262441 A01 1262441
B01 471272 A01 471272
B01 17007 A01 17007

$ cat nonmatch.txt
A05 44887670 A01 44887670
B10 8364597 A01 8364597
A05 9155966 A01 9155966
A05 86420950 A01 86420950
A10 75684694 A01 75684694
A04 71261964 A01 71261964
A04 115637044 A01 115637044
A07 9376758 A01 9376758
```

The script basically tries to match a particular regular expression on each line.   The expression matches if the two numbers in column 1 and 3 are identical (I'm using a back reference here to do this, which is why BSD `sed` won't be able to run this script).

If the two numbers are equal, the line gets written to `match.txt` and the script branches to the start and continues with the next line of input.

If the line does not match the regular expression, it gets written to `nonmatch.txt`.